# <hash_set> equality operator doesn't work in VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Sample code:

```
std::hash_set<int> hs1; // also i try std::unordered_set<int> - same effect 
std::hash_set<int> hs2;

hs1.insert(15);
hs1.insert(20);

hs2.insert(20);
hs2.insert(15);

assert(hs1 == hs2);
```

hash_set doesn't stores elements in some order defined by hash function... why?
Please note that this code works in VS2008 using stdext::hash_set.

Comment: Are you saying that you expect `hs1 == hs2` to be true, or that they *are* equal and you don't understand why?

Comment: I don't understand why they are NOT equal =)
This Assertion is failed and this is a problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like equality comparisons are broken for both `hash_set` and `unordered_set` in Visual C++ 2010.

I implemented a naive equality function for unordered containers using the language from the standard [quoted by Matthieu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772742/hash-set-equality-operator-doesnt-work-in-vs2010/2772880#2772880) to verify that it's a bug (just to be sure):

```
template <typename UnorderedContainer>
bool are_equal(const UnorderedContainer& c1, const UnorderedContainer& c2)
{
    typedef typename UnorderedContainer::value_type Element;
    typedef typename UnorderedContainer::const_iterator Iterator;
    typedef std::pair<Iterator, Iterator> IteratorPair;

    if (c1.size() != c2.size())
        return false;

    for (Iterator it(c1.begin()); it != c1.end(); ++it)
    {
        IteratorPair er1(c1.equal_range(*it));
        IteratorPair er2(c2.equal_range(*it));

        if (std::distance(er1.first, er1.second) != 
            std::distance(er2.first, er2.second))
            return false;

        // A totally naive implementation of is_permutation:
        std::vector<Element> v1(er1.first, er1.second);
        std::vector<Element> v2(er2.first, er2.second);

        std::sort(v1.begin(), v1.end());
        std::sort(v2.begin(), v2.end());

        if (!std::equal(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin()))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

It returns that `hs1` and `hs2` from your example are equal.  (Somebody let me know if you spot a bug in that code; I didn't really test it extensively...)

I'll file a defect report on Microsoft Connect.

Comment: Defect report link:  https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/557117/std-unordered-set-equality-comparison-broken-in-visual-c-2010

Comment: Thanks James :) I am not sure your comparison is optimal but I haven't seen any glaring bug either. Anyway even without code I gathered from the standard that the `unordered_set` equality is equivalent to `set` equality and should not depend on the order of insertions or the possibility of deletions.

Answer (score 2):

Finally found the reference in the final draft at 23.2.5, note 11:

> Two unordered containers `a` and `b` compare equal if `a.size() == b.size()` and, for every equivalent-key group `[Ea1,Ea2)` obtained from `a.equal_range(Ea1)`, there exists an equivalent-key group `[Eb1,Eb2)` obtained from `b.equal_range(Ea1)`, such that `distance(Ea1, Ea2) == distance(Eb1, Eb2)` and `is_permutation(Ea1, Ea2, Eb1)` returns `true`.

I would bet `hash_set` is now implemented in term of `unordered_set` (to begin with), but I still don't understand why in your case it would fail.

The complexity requirement is O(N) in the average case but degenerates to O(N<sup>2</sup>) in the worst case because of the linear-chaining implementation requirement.

Comment: As a solution i found boost::unordered_set.. but i once again was disappointed in Billy and his team

Answer (score 1):

i ask this question [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/c630514d-34f8-4b83-8df8-70990d1c1e83) but give no response =)
thanks for your feedback.

i also create some simple console test (just to be sure):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <hash_set>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{   
  stdext::hash_set<int> hs1, hs2;
  hs1.insert(10);
  hs1.insert(15);
  hs2.insert(15);
  hs2.insert(10);
  std::cout << ((hs1 == hs2) ? "It works!" : "It NOT works") << std::endl;
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

and compile it.
using vs2008 command prompt:

```
cl.exe HashSetTest.cpp /oHashSetTest2008.exe
```

using vs2010 command prompt:

```
cl.exe HashSetTest.cpp /oHashSetTest2010.exe
```

I really see different results =)